# Toggle a li span to show the child pages

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for assistance with my javascript toggle.

I can get the toggle to work when targeting the li with child pages, but when I add a span to the li and try and target that to show my child pages nothing happens.

This is my script:

```
$('.page_item_has_children ').click(function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     $(this).children('ul').toggle();
 });
```

This is my function:

```
/**
* List Child pages for Pages
*/
function my_list_child_pages() { 
global $post;
if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )
$childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0&link_after=<span class="active"></span>' );
else
$childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . 
$post->ID . '&echo=0&link_after=<span class="active"></span>' );
if ( $childpages ) {
$string = '<ul class="childPages">' . $childpages . '</ul>';
}
return $string;
}
add_shortcode('my_childpages', 'my_list_child_pages');
```

This is my CSS:

```
#child-pages {
background-color: rgba(85, 75, 70, 0.1);
}

#child-pages ul {
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
}

#child-pages ul li {
margin: 0;
}

#child-pages ul li ul li {
padding-left: 15px;
}

.childPages .children {
display: none;
}

.childPages .children.show {
display: block;
}

#child-pages ul .page_item_has_children span {
content: '+';
display: inline-block;
float: right;
}
```

I've added a span to .page_item_has_children, can I toggle the children by clicking this span?

Comment: You need to show your relevant markup for this code.

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)

Comment: Thanks @gurvinder372 updated now

Comment: @J-Dev can you add the resultant markup only. JS function and css doesn't seem relevant to your question.